# How can I extract a lessequal char from SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS?

Tags: sql-server, collation

When I create a table like this

```
create table char_test(
    item varchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)
go
```

I can store varchars containing **≥**

```
insert into char_test values ('≥');
```

When I do a

```
select item from  char_test;
```

I get

```
item
----------
=
```

But using

```
select replace(item, '≥', '>=') from  char_test;
```

gives

```
-----------------
>=
```

So the database knows the character. How can I convert the string to a nvarchar showing this character?

**Edit:**

The important fact here is, that SQL Server here maps some different characters to the same character without throwing errors or warnings.

I dare call this very bad design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

varchar doesn't support `≥`: unicode only

This includes the literal `'≥'` which is varchar too

<strike>Collation here doesn't matter: this is sorting and comparison only</strike> never seen this before!

Some more SQL to use your table

```
SELECT ASCII('≥'), CHAR(61), '≥'
GO
insert into char_test values ('≥');
GO
select item, ASCII(item) from  char_test;
GO
select replace(item, '≥', '>='), replace(item, '=', '>=') from  char_test;
GO


create table nchar_test(
    item varchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
    Nitem nvarchar(10) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)
go
insert into nchar_test values ('≥', N'≥');
GO
select item, ASCII(item), Nitem, UNICODE(Nitem) from nchar_test;
GO
```

Edit: after more playing

If you have a value then use CP 437

```
select CAST(Nitem COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS AS varchar) from nchar_test;
GO
select CAST(N'≥' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS AS varchar)
GO
```

Note: the ASCII is 242 but this won't give either :-)

```
SELECT
   ASCII(CAST(N'≥' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS AS varchar)),
   CHAR(242),
   CHAR(242) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS
```

You may be able to control this with database collation but frankly use unicode...

Comment: ah....it was the N before the '≥' I was missing, good catch.

Answer (score 2):

If I run this:

```
select UNICODE ( '≥' )
select UNICODE ( '=' )
select UNICODE ( item ) from  char_test;
```

They all return the same number, 61. I don't think the REPLACE proves that the character is being recognized. I even changed the char_test table to have the item column defined as nvarchar(10) and it still doesn't recognize the '≥'.

My best guess here is that you need a different collation, or to insert the data using a different method than SSMS (assuming you did the same as I did).

HTH